# How do I define an index for ASP.NET Core using EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using EF.Core in an ASP.NET core project. I have a model class, but can't find any documentation about what attributes to set on a property or the class to create an index or a unique index. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported in EF core (at least not yet). I believe this is in the pipeline to be a standard annotation instead of a separate downloadable package. You can use the fluent API instead:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasIndex(u => u.EmailAddress).Unique();
}
```

Comment: API has changed a little, now its `.HasIndex(o => o. EmailAddress).IsUnique(true);`.

Comment: do you know any idea on how to transform these by roslyn api

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes):

> Indexes can not be created using data annotations.

But, you can use the Fluent API for this purpose.